# BackboneJS with Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, backbone.js, requirejs

I have an application build with Codeigniter and I want to use BackboneJS for my frontend. I already build an API so that I can use the returned JSON from my Database, so the only thing I need is to integrate Backbone in my Codeigniter setup. I have also already an Backbone application, where I created most of the Views I need. So, in my Backbone's index.php I have:

```
<script data-main="js/config" src="js/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(['config'], function(config) {
        require(['app/mainpage']);
});
</script>
```

Also in my index.php, I have all the `div`'s where my backbone views are rendered.

I would like to know, how I do integrate this in Codeigniter. My file/folder-structure in Codeigniter is the typical CI-setup:

```
  - application
    - config
    - controllers
    - models
    - views
  - assets
    - css
    - img
  - system
index.php
.htaccess
```

So what is the best way to do this? Should I create an additional `js`-folder and then place my backbone-setup in that folder? If so, what about the `<script>`-code shown above? where to place it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You asked this a while ago, so I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but since I use a similar setup occasionally with AngularJS I suggest:

1. loading a view with all header contents as a layout. I use [this layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170728/codeigniter-import-js-css-img-properly/22172347#22172347)
2. Load your front-end client JS inside an include in /application/views/site/header.php, see [this repo for example](https://github.com/DesertLynx/blank_CI)

Once you have all the libraries loaded up you can then load each individual JS application (Angular uses Modules) or use a single application which loads partials (I assume backbone has this feature, as does Angular).

Oh also, a trap for the unweary: Codeigniter doesn't support JSON posts well, so RESTful APIs are not easy out of the box. If you need to receive JSON post data, the best I've found thus far is the utterly obtuse:

```
$phpArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```